# Using Input in User Defined Functions!(Python)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I am wondering, is there a way to use the `input()` function inside a user-defined function? I tried doing this

```
def  nameEdit(name):
    name = input()
    name = name.capitalize
    return name
```

Comment: And...? Does it give an error?

Answer (score 2):

Using `input` is fine. However, you aren't calling `name.capitalize`; you're just getting a reference to the method and assigning that to `name`. [Further, as pointed out by Bob, your function doesn't need a `name` argument.] The correct code would be

```
def nameEdit():
    name = input()
    name = name.capitalize()
    return name
```

or more simply:

```
def nameEdit():
    return input().capitalize()
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to pass in a name argument to the method since it isn't actually being used. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about asking for input from a user from a method? If so then this would be what you're looking for:

```
def nameEdit():
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    name = name.capitalize()
    return name
```

Comment: The tags say Python 3, so it'd be `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: Also, that won't run until you call the function. nameEdit()

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the raw_input, forgot about that. Updated my answer accordingly.